# Ionic can't find ANDROID_HOME on Windows 10

Tags: build, ionic-framework, environment-variables, android-sdk-2.3, emulation

Im using Ionic to build an Android app and I'm finding a problem that I cant work around or find an answer to. When I run `ionic build android` or `ionic emulate android` I get the following:

Error: Failed do find 'ANDROID_HOME'...

I believe I have added the correct variables to PATH and ANDROID_HOME under System Variables, but please check: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmGPW.jpg

The first image is ANDROID_HOME, the second shows where the sdk is located, the third is the Error itself and the fourth is my path variable.

I run it from Git Bash. Running as an administrator did not make any difference, I also tried reinstalling Android SDK (with Android Studio) in a different folder (was in %HOME%\AppData\Local\Android\ before) without any difference. Also tried to reboot after reinstalling SDK.

I also tried to run the SDK Manager first (C:\Android\sdk\tools\android.bat) and keeping it open while trying to build or emulate, but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a new system variable called `ANDROID_HOME` and as a value put the path to the android SDK installation directory.

[image]

[image]

For more information, please refer to the [installation guide](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html).

Comment: as I said in my question and showed in my images, I installed the sdk in C:\Android\sdk (Android studio gave me that option) and I have already added that to the ANDROID_HOME environment variable, which did not work. This is showed in the imgaes in the link I provided in the question.

Comment: Could you please send screen from Environment Variables window?